# Why avalanche breakdown in a PN junctions is said to be caused by minority carriers?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction, solid-state-devices

Reverse bias increases the depletion region (the "space charge region"). Remembering that electrons travel from (-) to (+) terminal, and that in reverse mode the (+) terminal is attached to the n-doped side of a PN junction, I would expect that current generation through avalanche breakdown is occuring due to *majority* carriers.

[image: PN junction in equilibrium] ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction))

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's the depletion region, there are no majority carriers.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, you're suggesting that avalanche occurs in the depletion region? why? and if the term "majority carrier" is undefineable in the depletion region, so does the term "minority carrier", no?

Comment: Where else can it occur?  It's conducting elsewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, to my understanding, avalanche, or rather impact ionization, occurs anywhere, but at a high reverse bias it's becoming significant.

Comment: Yeah, not many carriers in the depletion region.    You can't get a high reverse bias except where there are no free charges.  (Well, you can't get much forward bias where there are free charges either.)

Comment: Impact ionization is not happening everywhere, there needs to be enough energy gained from the E field between collisions to ionize another atom/electron.

Comment: right! so why the impacts are said to be caused by minority carriers? i.e. by \$p_n,\ n_p\$?

Comment: Minority carriers near depletion region are swept to the other side with high KE and reveal more minority carriers, and they in turn are swept to the other side....and it continues. Also, there are no charges near the depletion region ( hence the name). The positive charge is shown to indicate the absence of electrons and vice versa. This is important, otherwise more recombination would have taken place, and there wont be any minority carrier movement to other side.

Answer (score 1):

The *majority carriers* operate when the PN junction is forward biased.  The *minority carriers* operate when the PN junction is reverse biased.  Since  avalanche breakdown occurs when the PN junction is reverse biased, it can only be caused by the *minority carriers.* **Therefore, it is correct to say that avalanche breakdown is caused by *minority carriers***.